# When I set background image it makes everything inside it disappear (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, constraints

[image]I have a custom cell inside it there is a cover image that has inside it a profile pic but when i set the background image it makes the profile picture disappears.

what am i missing out??

Comment: Could you share your code, please?

Comment: I get it In storyboard Yo need to rearrange images. Profile image is getting hidden inside Cover image.  Please share your storyboard for cell.

Comment: @seugjun I added picture

Comment: @Kudos i tried to put it in content view but it still disappeared

Comment: Did you tried setting profile picture image?

Comment: @Kudos yes i did

Comment: Buttons and labels Are those also hidden?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231454/discussion-between-masa-and-kudos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot see your code, I can't tell exactly why this happens but I think the problem is you put **Profile Pic** inside **Cover Pic** Also, other views such as **Full Name Label, Position Label...** should also be in the same level or position as Cover Pic in the view hierarchy. I hope this will solve your problem.